# How to implement http2 streaming client?

Tags: c, streaming, libcurl, server-sent-events, http2

I was looking to create a http2 streaming client in C which is able to connect to server, create stream and keep listening for messages from server on that stream without cancelling the stream unless explicitly cancelled or network issue.

I was trying to implement it via libcurl but seems there is no such support in libcurl, at best what I can do is just make a request with curl and not have a timeout. Then curl will just sit there waiting for the transfer to start or complete, until the server does that. And when one transfer is done, the client can just issue another request and go back to waiting...

But I just want to maintain the stream rather than issuing another request to server after receiving message. 
I don't want to use GRPC which provides similar functionality but along with it comes lots of complexity of libs and platform dependencies to be resolved.

Is there any other C based library or any http2 stream reference which I should have a look at?

Comment: Have you tried to set CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION and process server responses in that callback (after accumulating each complete response)?

Comment: HTTP/2 is for HTTP you know, so it needs a request. That restriction is not due to libcurl but due to the protocol...